# Haskell: Increment elements of a list by cumulative length of previous lists

Tags: haskell

Here is the list of lists: `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]]`

How can I increment each element of the second list by the length of the first list, and increment the third list by the length of the first list + second list? **The first list should remain unchanged.**

Intended output: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10]]`

Since the first list has length 3, the second list is generated by `[1+3, 2+3, 3+3, 4+3]`.

Since the first list + second list combined have length 7, the third list is generated by `[1+7, 2+7, 3+7]`.

Ideally it should work with any number of lists.

So far, I've had slight sucess using this:

`scanl1 (\xs ys -> [y + length xs | y <- ys]) [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]]`

which outputs: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[5,6,7]]`

Comment: Looks like a good case of *stateful list traversal*. For this sort of things, you might want to try using the [mapAccumL](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL) library function.

Comment: You can also proceed by explicit recursion. Define an auxiliary recursive function `f listOfLists counter` where the counter tells by how much we should increase the first list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this. A simple recursion is one approach:

```
lst :: [[Int]]
lst = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]]

incrLength :: [[Int]] -> Int -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
incrLength [] _ result = result
incrLength (x:xs) amount result =
   incrLength xs (amount + length x) (result ++ [map (+amount) x])
```

(Edit: it is more efficient to use (:) in this function. See @amalloy comment below. The result then has to be reversed.

```
incrLength :: [[Int]] -> Int -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
incrLength [] _ result = reverse result
incrLength (x:xs) amount result =
   incrLength xs (amount + length x) (map (+amount) x : result)
```

End Edit)

Another approach is to use `scanl`. We use `length` to get the length of the inner lists, then accumulate using `scanl`.

```
 map length lst                      -- [3,4,3]
 scanl (+) 0 $ map length lst        -- [0,3,7,10]
 init $ scanl (+) 0 $ map length lst -- [0,3,7]
```

Then we zip the lst and the accumulated value together, and map one over the other.

```
 incrLength' :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
 incrLength' lst = 
      [map (+ snd y) (fst y) | y <- zip lst addlst]
    where 
       addlst =init $scanl (+) 0 $ map length lst 

main = do
    print $ incrLength lst 0 []    -- [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10]]
```

Comment: Why are we doing this with tail recursion and `(++)` to append at the end? Laziness with `(:)` is way more natural and efficient.

Comment: Tail recursion because I am a recovering Lisp programmer. Why is (:) more efficient, please?

Comment: `(++)` takes time linear in the size of the first argument, so using it to build up a list one item at a time takes quadratic time. But also, tail recursion is usually pretty bad in Haskell in general, because of laziness. You build up a giant thunk, producing no result at all until the whole list is ready. If you just cons items onto the result of the recursive call, GHC will yield items as they're ready, and delay the rest until they're needed.

Comment: @FrancisKing - In Haskell, operator (++) has to *duplicate* its left operand. This is because you have to alter the null *next* pointer in the very last list node, to have it point to the beginning of the right operand. And because of general immutability, the library function may not do that on your original left operand, so it has to build a copy of it, and then alter the last pointer *in that copy*. So if you use (++) repeatedly to grow a list towards the right, you get quadratic cost :-(

Answer (score 4):

`scanl1` is a good idea, but it's not quite right, because you don't want your accumulator to be a list, but rather to be an integer. So you really want `scanl`, not `scanl1`. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to see how to adjust your solution - given that you managed to write something almost-right with `scanl1`, I don't think you'll find it too hard once you have the right function.

In the comments, jpmariner suggests [`mapAccumL` :: (s -> a -> (s, b)) -> s -> [a] -> (s, [b]))](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL). That's perfectly typed for what we want to do, so let's see how it would look.

```
import Data.Traversable (mapAccumL)

addPreviousLengths :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
addPreviousLengths = snd . mapAccumL go 0
  where go n xs = (n + length xs, map (+ n) xs)

λ> addPreviousLengths [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10]]
```

`mapAccumL` really is the best tool for this job - there's not much unnecessary complexity involved in using it. But if you're trying to implement this from scratch, you might try the recursive approach Francis King suggested. I'd suggest a lazy algorithm instead of the tail-recursive algorithm, though:

```
incrLength :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
incrLength = go 0
  where go _ [] = []
        go amount (x:xs) =
          map (+ amount) x : go (amount + length x) xs
```

It works the same as the mapAccumL version. Note that both versions are lazy: they consume only as much of the input list as necessary. This is an advantage not shared by a tail-recursive approach.

```
λ> take 3 . incrLength $ repeat [1]
[[1],[2],[3]]
λ> take 3 . addPreviousLengths $ repeat [1]
[[1],[2],[3]]
```